# Pass Integer array from C++ to Python using IPC/Shared memory

Tags: python, c++

what is the best method to pass a  int C++ Array to a python program using shared memory? for example i've array as defined:*

```
int  arr[100];
for(int i =0;i<100;i++) {
 arr[i] = i*2;
}
```

and i would get on python program:
[0,2,4,6.... 200] 
?

Thanks

Comment: For IPC i love to work with rpclib: https://github.com/rpclib/rpclib. Very easy to set up in your C++ code, i'm sure python has good rpc libraries as well. I once used shared memory for IPC and it was a hassle since you need to take care of OS-specific details and the communication yourself.

Comment: Just write the array elements to a fifo or a piece of shared memory and read it in python? Im confused because you are asking about IPC but did you even try to look up any IPC methods. If you did you would see that for whatever operating system you are using there are a lot.... Also you don't mention the operating so it's hard for anyone to give you the simplest answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a python module using pybind11 and create a function that exposes the array content.
pybind11 tutorial to get an idea of the complexity:

https://bastian.rieck.me/blog/posts/2018/cmake_cpp_pybind11_hard_mode/